# Cant hide items per page and pagination in datatable when less then number displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a `Datatable` which if 1 page is returned i want to hide the 'Items per pages' `dropdown` list and also the `pagination`. This also needs to work when filtering the table.

I am using the:

```
.DataTable().page.info()
```

Below is the code i have

```
"fnDrawCallback": function () {
    var accountSearchDataTableInfo = $('#accountSearchDataTable').DataTable().page.info();

    if (accountSearchDataTableInfo.pages == '1') {
        console.log(accountSearchDataTableInfo.pages == '1')
        $('#accountSearchDataTable_length').hide();
        $('#accountSearchDataTable_paginate').hide();
    }

    if (accountSearchDataTableInfo.pages == 1) {
        console.log(accountSearchDataTableInfo.pages == 1)
        $('#accountSearchDataTable_length').hide();
        $('#accountSearchDataTable_paginate').hide();
    }
}
```

And this gives...

**Initial table load table info**

[image]

**Filtered table info**

[image]

As you can see from my `IF` i have tried a number and string but when i do `console.log` on these it comes back `true` but the items are still displayed.

I have tried `.hide()` and also `.css('display', 'none')` but nothing seems to be working and i'm at a loss what else to try.

When i look at the `element` in `Dev tools` the `style` attribute is added but nothing after it:

**Initial table load**

[image]

**Filtered table**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I was looking for the parent `DIV` but it appear that if i used each individual identifier i can hide them. so my `IF` now look like

```
if (accountSearchDataTableInfo.pages == '1') {
    $('.mb-2').hide(); // Items per page DD
    $('#accountSearchDataTable_previous').hide(); // Pagintator 'Previous' button
    $('#accountSearchDataTable_next').hide(); // Pagintator 'Next' button
    $('.paginate_button').hide(); // Pagintator page '1' button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below api to determine pages number

> table.api().page.info().pages

As stated in documentation:

https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()

And use `drawCallback()` after table is draw As documented here:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback

Example how to hide pagination when page is 1 or less:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        var api = this.api();

        var pagination = $(this).closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_paginate');
        pagination.toggle(api.page.info().pages > 1);
    }
} );
```